# Dev C++: How to fix "Unrecognisable insn, internal compiler error" (full error in description)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I was writing some simple C++ code using DevC++ when this error came up:

[image]

I have no clue as to why I am getting this upon initialising a vector array (a graph adjacency list).
I couldn't co much to solve this problem since I am not an expert in c++ compilers. I tried reinstalling the program but that didn't help at all.

My compiler is **TDM-GCC** and in the compiler options I added "**-std=c++11**", which is executed when calling the compiler.

Comment: You broke the compiler. Time to upgrade it.

Comment: @Botje What do you mean by that :) ? Do you suggest I should uninstall it and install a new one?

Comment: The Dev-C++ environment and the compiler supplied with it is very much out of date. There are other more modern and up-to-date environments that are freely available (for example Code::Blocks), as well as distributions of GCC that are also much more modern (for example MinGW).

Comment: It appears your compiler is not happy creating an array of size 100M containing `std::vector<int>` objects.

Comment: Do you need so large array? I suggest you should rethink the algorithm.

Comment: @MikeCAT This is a coding problem with a memory limit of 64mb of memory. The array takes up around 50mb, which  means I can create an array this large.

Comment: @StLuke5 Where did you get this 50MB number from? 10003 * 10003 * 4(sizeof int) = 400 MB. And actually your code is creating 100M `std::vector`s, so probably two or three times that.

Comment: Also it seems your code contains `N*K` iterations and it will be too many for common online judge system.

Comment: Lets say that an `std::vector<int>` object is 8 bytes (i.e. `sizeof(std::vector<int>) == 8`). Then an array of over 100 million such elements will need over 800 million bytes.That's quite a bit more than 64 MiB.

Comment: @Botje Yes, you are right, I made a mistake  in the code. I wanted to create a vector array like this : vector<int> adj[K]; However, I know what caused the problem and I have just solved it.

Comment: If you solved the problem, and think it might be useful for others to know the solution, then please post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
std::vector<int> adj[NK];
```

defines an array of 100 million `std::vector` objects, along with a static initializer to create all of them.

Did you mean to create a single vector of size 100M?

```
std::vector<int> adj(NK);
```

Comment: Actually, that was a mistype. I wanted a vector array like this : vector<int>  adj[N]; However, I have just found the solution to my problem and I am going to post it soon

Comment: Should probably just use a `vector<vector<int>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that I made a mistake in the code, it still compiled successfully after a very simple fix. The compiler used to be a 64-bit Release version. I changed the field to the 32-bit  Release and the problem disappeared, despite the ridiculous  amount of memory my program had needed.

[image]

Please note that your mileage may vary and this solution might have some side effects I am not aware of. However, this worked just fine for me and it seems that all my other c++ files compile without any errors.